# What is wrong? Runtime Error when running C code

Tags: c

I cannot find out why am I having a RunTime Error when I compile this code. Can someone tell me what is broken in my code?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int ai[100], n=0, m=0, test=0, count=0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &m);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &ai[i]);
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        test = ai[j]+ai[j+1];
        if(test<=m)
        {
            count++;
        } else
        {
            j=j-1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What runtime error did you get? Are you actually asking about Time Limit Exceeded? OR is it a compiler error? That would more or less be the opposite of a runtime error.

Comment: j<n-1 in second loop

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Make sure that `n` is not bigger than `100`.

Comment: what you want to count?

Comment: When `j == n - 1`, what is `test = ai[j]+ai[j+1];`? (hint: `ai[n]` is one past the end of your array... if `n == 100`, and much much beyond the end with `n >= 100`)

Comment: I am curious to know how exactly you posted your code. If you have copy-pasted, then you seem to have quite weird an editor. The cumulative indentation, if it is how your code actually looks to you, is very distracting when trying to debug anything. I recommend to adopt a consistent indentation scheme. I proposed one (initally to help reasoning about the now deleted answer below).

Comment: @Yunnosch - trick... After the 3-`\`\`\`` before the code, just add `c`, e.g. `\`\`\`c` and it will enable syntax highlighting.

Comment: @AppyGG Same recommendation to you. If you apply indentation you do not stumble like in your deleted answer.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica I spotted that. Thanks.

Comment: Am I the only one who does not understand what runtime error OP is referring to?

Comment: It can be a couple of things. What is being accomplished with `j = j - 1;` inside the 2nd `for` loop -- that would really screw things up for a small `m` (potentially infinite loop screw up). Nope @Yunnosch -- I'm right there with you... The 2nd loop should also be `for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) { test = ai[j-1] + ai[j]; ...`

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what your "runtime error" is, but you have two problems in this code. A possible infinite loop with integer overflow and access of an undefined value. These can both trigger certain error at runtime as they are both causing undefined behaviour.

If `m` is sufficiently small your loop will be stuck when `ai[j]+ai[j+1]`  is bigger than `m`. As you decrement `j` you will be adding the same values again. Also `count` will overflow.

But it even gets worse, you run into undefined behaviour in any case. As  `j` is bound by `n` and `n` is the number of written values in `ai`. You also access `ai[j+1]` this will be an invalid value for the last iteration as it is never defined.

You should not modify the loop counter of a `for`loop outside of the declaration, because situations like this can arise. A for loop is a counting loop and thats it, it should be clear that it runs 10 times when `n = 10` for example.

Comment: An answer to this question I would expect to start off with "I assume that by 'runtime error' you mean...".

Comment: @Yunnosch Added a preamble, even if I fear that OP will not read any more of this. Especially as the wrong assumption that `j`is negative on the array access also got an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        test = ai[j]+ai[j+1];
        if(test<=m)
        {
            count++;
        } else
        {
            j=j-1;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Note that:

- `j=j-1;` can take j to negative value => **Runtime error here.**
- When j = n -1, `test = ai[j]+ai[j+1];` => aj[j+1] <=> ai[n], index should be <= n - 1

Comment: An answer to this question I would expect to start off with "I assume that by 'runtime error' you mean...".

Comment: `j` will not be negative when the array is accessed, so there is no problem in regard to this.